# How do I calculate $ \iiint_D|z|\,dx\,dy\,dz$ without using spherical coordinates?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the following integral:

$$
\iiint_D|z|\,dx\,dy\,dz
$$

which I need to integrate over the set:

$$
D = \{x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}: x^2 + z^2 \leq y^2, y^2 \leq 4 \}
$$

I have a problem determinining the correct intervals (I think I'll know how to go from there). Right now I have: $y \in [-2,2 ]$.

1. How do I set interval for $x$ and $z$?
2. When calculating triple integral from $|z|$, should I consider two cases: $z<0$ and $z \geq 0$ (and calculate both integrals separately) or is there any better way?

Comment: Can you use polar coordinates instead?

Comment: I was thinking about a solution without using polar coordinates either but any advice (even with spherical coordinates) would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the integral as $$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-|y|}^{|y|} \int_{-\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}} |z| \, dz dx dy.$$ The inner integral is equal to $y^2 - x^2$, so the remaining computation should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Can you please explain this intervals?

Comment: Sure. First, $y^2 \le 4$ means that $y$ must lie in between $-2$ and $2$.  Second, fix such a value of $y$. Since $x^2 + z^2 \le y^2$, you have in particular that $x^2 \le y^2$. Taking square roots this leads to $|x| \le |y|$, so that $-|y| \le x \le |y|$. Third, fix such values $y$ and $x$.  The range of values of $z$ is forced to be $z^2 \le y^2 - x^2$, which is equivalent to $-\sqrt{y^2 - x^2} \le z \le \sqrt{y^2 - x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The way to remain sane here is to note that the integral when $y < 0$ is the same as that when $y > 0$, and similarly for $x$ and $z$.  Then we have
$$
2\int_0^2dy\, 2 \int_0^2 dx 2 \int_0^{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}|z|\,dz= 8\int_0^2dy \int_0^y\sqrt{y^2 - x^2} dx 
$$
$$
8\int_0^2dy \int_0^y\sqrt{y^2 - x^2} dx = 
8\int_0^2 dy \left[ \frac{1}{2}\left( x\sqrt{y^2-x^2}+ y^2 \sin^{-1} \frac{x}{y} \right) \right]_0^y 
$$
$$
4\int_0^2 dy \left[ \left( x\sqrt{y^2-x^2}+ y^2 \sin^{-1} \frac{x}{y} \right) \right]_{x=0}^y = 8 \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^2 y^2  dy = \frac{32\pi}{3}
$$

OK, I guess we did not remain sane, but it was close.

Comment: Can you explain how $$\int_0^{\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}} |z| \, dz = \sqrt{y^2 - x^2}?$$